# IRC/Colloquy sleep message

Tags: irc, colloquy

I'm using Colloquy for irc, and in the general section of the preferences there is a sleep message that I can set, but I have no idea how to change my status to sleeping.. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`/away <away message>` command](http://colloquy.info/project/wiki/Documentation/CommandReference#Othercommands). If you don't put any message it will unset your Away status.

Answer (score 1):

Select *Sleep* from the Apple menu, or close your laptop lid. Colloquy gets notified when the computer is going to sleep, and disconnects all IRC connections, using the sleep message as quit message.